# IBAPI: how to place order when open auction is done?

Tags: python-3.x, ib-api

I am a newer to the IBAPI.  I want to place an order in the continuous trading phase after 9:30 if the open price is good for me according to some rules. After reading the document, I plan to place order in the realtimeBar() callback function, because this function will be called every 3 seconds to receive the realtime bar data.

Is there any better solution? such as sleep 100 milliseconds, wake to check and place order?
Or register some service to receive the open auction finished trigger message?

thanks a lot
Arthur

Comment: Was there any particular problem when you tried to do it?

Comment: If I place the order in the realtimeBar(), it will be 3 seconds later. It would be perfect if I can place the order as soon as open auction is finished.

Comment: You should edit your question accordingly so that it contains a clear and specific problem statement.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but you might want to practice in TWS first using orders 'market on open' https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/basic_orders.html or 'good after time' https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/classIBApi_1_1Order.html#a04f61266450f61c36fae22946c74a8f3

Comment: Thanks mkrieger1 & brian. I would place an order in the continuous trading phase after 9:30 if the open price is good for me according to some rules.So the  'market on open' or  'good after time'  may not be good solution.

Comment: en , Now I think it should be ok to do in the realtimeBar() because there will be short break between  the auction period and 9:30. thanks.

Comment: I don't think the open price is all that relevant anymore but there is a ticktype `OPEN = 14;` that you may want to look at.  It doesn't come with realTimeBar but the regular reqMktData.  I've never looked at when it comes or if it's accurate.

Comment: Auction price is not always the price at 9:30:00, auction can be as late as 9:45:00